# How I can run docker containers on the remote host?

Tags: jenkins, docker

I want run two containers on remote host from a Jenkins job. I have ssh access, but I don't want use ssh for it.

It currently works as:

```
ssh -T <HOST> docker login -u testuser -p testpassword registry:5000


ssh -T <HOST> docker pull registry:5000/db:${VERSION}


ssh -T <HOST> docker pull registry:5000/app:${VERSION}
```

How can I do it without `ssh -T` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For this task I used docker remote API.

Answer (score 3):

Install the Docker client on Jenkins, and then setup the Docker servers and clients with TLS keys. Here's a quick run through of the commands to setup a self signed CA+keys:

## Self signed CA server

```
# work in a secure folder
mkdir docker-ca && chmod 700 docker-ca && cd docker-ca
# generate a key pair for the CA
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out ca-key.pem 2048
# setup CA certificate
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca-key.pem -sha256 -out ca.pem
  # make sure to set CN
```

## Server certificate

```
# generate a new host key pair
openssl genrsa -out myserver-key.pem 2048
# generate certificate signing request (CSR)
openssl req -subj "/CN=myserver" -new -key myserver-key.pem -out myserver.csr
# setup extfile for ip's to allow
echo "subjectAltName = IP:$myserver_ip, IP:127.0.0.1" >extfile.cnf
# sign the key by the CA
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in myserver.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem \
  -CAcreateserial -out myserver-cert.pem -extfile extfile.cnf
# test server by updating service:
/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 --tlsverify \
  --tlscacert=/etc/docker/ca.pem --tlscert=/etc/docker/myserver-cert.pem \
  --tlskey=/etc/docker/myserver-key.pem
```

You'll want to update the server startup scripts with the TLS options above, this varies per platform, but the systemd file would be copied from `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` to `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service`, edited, and then loaded with `sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo systemctl restart docker`.

## Client certificate

```
# create a client key pair
openssl genrsa -out client-key.pem 2048
# generate csr for client key
openssl req -subj '/CN=client' -new -key client-key.pem -out client.csr
# configure request to support client
echo extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth >extfile.cnf
# sign the client key with the CA
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in client.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem \
  -CAcreateserial -out client-cert.pem -extfile extfile.cnf
# test client with
docker --tlsverify \
  --tlscacert=ca.pem --tlscert=client-cert.pem --tlskey=client-key.pem \
  -H=tcp://127.0.0.1:2376 info`
```

In `$HOME/.docker` you can add: ca.pem, key.pem, and cert.pem. Then `export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1` and `export DOCKER_HOST=your_docker_server` as part of your login script (.bashrc).

Comment: I have TLS certificates. My registry works throught them.
How I can do pull without ssh on the *remote host*?

Comment: Woops, forgot one last detail, you can either `docker -H hostname ...` or set DOCKER_HOST in your environment. If you have TLS setup on the remote docker engine, and in your client, and configure the server to listen on the port, per the above instructions, you can access the server remotely.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a docker client into the Jenkins Box and use it to update your containers.

Comment: I have docker client in Jenkins Box and I have TLS certificates.
I want use pull without ssh.